# How do i Highlight the only div where file is dragged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with `input type="file"` and total there are `3 inputs`. so on client request i make some changes in design and hide the default styling on `input type="file"` and convert it into **drag and drop** styling. now the problem is when i **drag** the file in `input` section i need to highlight that div where file is **dragged** because i have 4 inputs it only highlight the last script i wrote for highlighting the **div**

**HMTL**

```
    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="exampleInputFile">File Before</label>
                                    <div class="file-drop-area border">

                                        <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" class="file_before files" name="file_before[]" multiple required>
                                        <p class="message" name="drag">Drag your files here or click in this area.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="file_before_append"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputFile">File After</label>
                                <div class="file_after-drop-area border">
                                    <input  type="file" id="exampleInputFile" class="file_after files" name="file_after[]" multiple required>
                                    <p class="message">Drag your files here or click in this area.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="file_after_append"></div>
                            </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 <script>

        var $fileInput = $('.file_after');
        var $droparea = $('.file_after-drop-area');

        $fileInput.on('dragenter focus click', function () {
            $droparea.addClass('is-active');

        });

        $fileInput.on('dragleave blur drop', function () {
            $droparea.removeClass('is-active');
        });

</script>

<script>

        var $fileInput = $('.file_before');
        var $droparea = $('.file-drop-area');

        $fileInput.on('dragenter focus click', function () {
            $droparea.addClass('is-active');

        });

        $fileInput.on('dragleave blur drop', function () {
            $droparea.removeClass('is-active');
        });

</script>
Runs only the 2nd script you can say it runs the last script
```

**CSS**

```
     form input.files{
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .border{
            border: 2px dashed #d2d6de;
            height: 40px;
        }
        form .message{
             width: 100%;
             height: 100%;
             text-align: center;
             line-height: 35px;
             overflow: hidden;
             color: #d2d6de;
         }
        label.col-sm-10 {
            padding-left: initial;
        }
        .file-drop-area {
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            width: 450px;
            max-width: 100%;
            transition: 0.2s;
        }
        .file-drop-area.border.is-active {
            border: 2px dashed black;
        }
        .file_after-drop-area {
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            width: 450px;
            max-width: 100%;
            transition: 0.2s;
        }
        .file_after-drop-area.border.is-active {
            border: 2px dashed black;
        }
```

now i want to highlight the div where i hover the drag file
[jsfiddle link](https://codepen.io/abdullah-faraz/pen/povLROR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the same variable for different methods here.
By using var fileinput.

[`Check out`](https://jsfiddle.net/4dtbwhze/1/) the fiddle I have copied and modified